# Image is not visible in Tabitem Header in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, tabitem

I am designing a `TabItem` by adding `StackPanel` which contains an `Image` and `Textblock`, and the XAML code is as follows,

**XAML:**

```
<sdk:TabItem    
      Name="adminTab" 
      BorderBrush="Black" 
      Background="#F5C162" 
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
      Margin="0,0,0,-14" 
      BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
    <sdk:TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Background="#F5C162" 
                    Width="80" Height="30" 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Margin="-7,-3,-11,-23" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Name="ico1" 
                   Height="20" Width="20" 
                   Source="TabIcons/Admin.ico" 
                   Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,5,0,0"/> 
            <TextBlock Text="Admin" Margin="5,5,0,0" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </StackPanel>
    </sdk:TabItem.Header>
</sdk:TabItem>
```

I am supposed to display image but actually it appears as below,

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the "build action" for the `Admin.ico` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `.ico` image formats are supported by Silverlight.

From the [`Image.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28VS.95%29.aspx) MSDN:

> Silverlight does not support all image formats. See BitmapImage for
>   information on the types of image sources and formats that can be used
>   for an Image.

On that [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page:

> The BitmapImage can be used to reference images in the JPEG and PNG
>   file formats.

This is different than the `Image` control used in WPF/Windows8 which does appear to support `.ico` files.

Unfortunately, I think you'll have to try converting your ICO file to a PNG or JPG.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight only can render most types of JPG and PNG.

[ImageClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You will need to convert your ico file to PNG or JPG.

[ico to png converter](http://www.convertico.com/)